# Creating a conditional column in DAX based on 3 other columns

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements, dax, powerbi-desktop

I've created new columns with a condition tied to them before, but typically it was just based on one other column.  Here's where I'm suck:

| Package | Software | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Package1 | Software1 | Complete |
| Package1 | Software2 | Ready |
| Package1 | Software3 | Complete |
| Package2 | Software1 | No Start |
| Package2 | Software6 | Ready |
| Package3 | Software4 | Complete |

So a "Package" is a group of Software titles bundled together.  I need to create a 4th column based on this criteria:
If **All** Software Titles in a Package is in the Complete Status, then TRUE, if not then FALSE.

I can clarify further if needed because it doesn't feel like I'm explaining it clearly enough.

I've tried multiple IF statements, but to no avail.  I figured there's got to be an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go with:

```
PackageComplete = 
  var cnt =
    COUNTROWS(
      FILTER(
        'PackageTable',
        'PackageTable'[Package] = EARLIER(PackageTable[Package]) &&
        'PackageTable'[Status] <> "Complete"
      )
    )
  return IF(cnt > 0, FALSE(), TRUE())
```

Comment: Sam - that worked perfectly! This will help me out in quite a few reports.  Thanks so much.